# Re-Enable message to notify user of non-existance

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Our Wso2 IS (5.7.4) implementation was setup with reCaptcha. At that time, the message a customer would receive on screen during a username recovery to tell them the user was not found was disabled. Leaving only the message of "An email has been....".

We are looking to turn the message back on, but cannot find the setting. Anybody know where this is at?

Comment: You can try adding <NotifyUserExistence>true</NotifyUserExistence> inside the <Recovery> section in identity.xml.

Comment: That change did it. My current identity.xml had the Recovery section commented out. I left that and added a new Recovery section with just the NotifyUserExistence setting. This worked as desired.

Comment: You can use the existing <Recovery> section by only uncommenting the <Recovery> tags. You can find the final output in the answer of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **WSO2 Identity Server 5.7.0** we can use the `<NotifyUserExistence>true</NotifyUserExistence>` in order to enable the notification for the user existence in the recovery process. This configuration can be added to the `<Recovery>` section of the `identity.xml` file located in `<IS-HOME>/repository/conf/identity` directory. After adding the configuration the recovery section may be like as follows.

```
<Recovery>
     <Other-Uncommented/Commented-Configurations>
     <NotifyUserExistence>true</NotifyUserExistence>
</Recovery>
```